# Get error when testing Get method unit test

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-runner

I am trying to test a http service which contain a getByList(id) method but I have these two errors :

```
   Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: https://localhost:44394/api/materials", found none.
   Error: Expected no open requests, found 1: GET https://localhost:44394/api/materials/c2789b86-8d62-4259-81d0-1d13e687e005
```

This is my mocked services :

```typescript
    class MockGenericService<T> {
      constructor(protected http : HttpClient, url :string){}
      url =''
      getListById(filter) : Observable<T[]> {
       return this.http.get(this.url + '/' + filter, this.prepareHeader()).pipe(map(res => res as 
        T[]))}
    private prepareHeader(): Object {
      let headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers = headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');
      return { headers: headers };}}
    class MockSubCauseService extends MockGenericService<ItemDamageModel>{ 
      constructor( http : HttpClient){  
       super(http,'')}
       url = 'https://localhost:44394/api/causes' }
And this is my spec.ts:

    
     fdescribe('SubCauseService', () => {

       let injector: TestBed;
       let service: MockSubCauseService;
       let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
    beforeEach(() => {
     TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
     providers: [MockSubCauseService
     ],
     })
    injector = getTestBed();
    service = injector.get(MockSubCauseService);
    httpMock = injector.get(HttpTestingController);
    });
    fit('should be created', () => {
     const service: MockSubCauseService = TestBed.get(MockSubCauseService);
     expect(service).toBeTruthy();
     });
    fit('can test HttpClient.getAll', () => {
     const testData: Array<ItemDamageModel>= [{  "id": "8286adac-eacf-43f2-acfa-9be68de70aba",
     "name": "Smoking"}];
     service.getListById('3e211c50-67cc-4d3f-a111-686c06336d26').subscribe((res) => {
        expect(res).toEqual(testData);
      })
      const req = httpMock.expectOne(service.url);
      expect(req.request.method).toBe('GET');
      req.flush(testData);
      })
      afterEach(() => {
       httpMock.verify();
      });  }}
```

It works fine in the Postman But here I don't understand why it shows me these errors ! Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your question. At the very least break-up the second code snippet into 2 snippets (see `And this is my spec.ts:`).

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to include the id in expectations:

```js
const req = httpMock.expectOne(`${service.url}/3e211c50-67cc-4d3f-a111-686c06336d26`);
```